# Extracting information from a single XML nodes children without getting other children's values

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm trying to get one of the XML nodes to give me the values of its child elements however the solution that i have (so far) shows me the child elements of all the elements.

This is the format that the XML is in

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fittings>
    <fitting name="Caracal - Rapid light">
        <description value=""/>
        <shipType value="Caracal"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 0" type="Damage Control II"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 1" type="Ballistic Control System II"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 2" type="Ballistic Control System II"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 3" type="Ballistic Control System II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 0" type="Adaptive Invulnerability Field II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 1" type="Large Shield Extender II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 2" type="Large Shield Extender II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 3" type="X5 Prototype Engine Enervator"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 4" type="Warp Disruptor II"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 0" type="Rapid Light Missile Launcher II"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 1" type="Rapid Light Missile Launcher II"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 2" type="Rapid Light Missile Launcher II"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 3" type="Rapid Light Missile Launcher II"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 4" type="Rapid Light Missile Launcher II"/>
        <hardware slot="rig slot 0" type="Medium Bay Loading Accelerator I"/>
        <hardware slot="rig slot 1" type="Medium Anti-EM Screen Reinforcer I"/>
        <hardware slot="rig slot 2" type="Medium Core Defense Field Extender I"/>
    </fitting>
    <fitting name="Caracal - heavy">
        <description value=""/>
        <shipType value="Caracal"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 0" type="Damage Control II"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 1" type="Ballistic Control System II"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 2" type="Ballistic Control System II"/>
        <hardware slot="low slot 3" type="Ballistic Control System II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 0" type="Warp Disruptor II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 1" type="X5 Prototype Engine Enervator"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 2" type="Large Shield Extender II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 3" type="Large Shield Extender II"/>
        <hardware slot="med slot 4" type="Small Shield Booster II"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 0" type="Heavy Missile Launcher I"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 1" type="Heavy Missile Launcher I"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 2" type="Heavy Missile Launcher I"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 3" type="Heavy Missile Launcher I"/>
        <hardware slot="hi slot 4" type="Heavy Missile Launcher I"/>
        <hardware slot="rig slot 0" type="Medium Capacitor Control Circuit I"/>
        <hardware slot="rig slot 1" type="Medium Core Defense Field Extender I"/>
        <hardware slot="rig slot 2" type="Medium Core Defense Capacitor Safeguard I"/>
    </fitting>
</fittings>
```

There can be many different  elements in one XML document

My code is trying to get the 'type' in each hardware child in one fitting. My current code will retrieve every type in the whole XML document and i'm having trouble isolating it to just one of the  nodes. Any advice would be very appreciated :)

```
    'Import XML data from slected file'
    Dim ImportEntry As XElement = XElement.Load(Selected)

    'value of selected fitting ("name" value)
    Dim PropLook As String = ImportSelect.SelectedValue

    'find and show fitted ship items
    Dim hardware_type = ImportEntry...<hardware>.Attributes("type")
    For Each Attribute In hardware_type
        FitProporties.Items.Add(Attribute.Value)
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way you can try :

```
Dim PropLook As String = ImportSelect.SelectedValue

'filter <fitting> by its name attribute...'
'then search all corresponding <hardware> child ...'
'and get its type attribute value'
Dim hardware_type = ImportEntry.<fittings>.<fitting>.Where(Function(x) x.@name = PropLook).<hardware>.Attributes("type")
For Each Attribute In hardware_type
    FitProporties.Items.Add(Attribute.Value)
Next
```

Comment: This doesn't return values for some reason. :(

Comment: Worked fine for me, tested using your XML sample with hardcoded `PropLook` string. Debug your application and find out the problem.